# How to access gemfire cache from jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, gemfire, oql

I have a gemfire cache v8.2.1 from which I want to access data using a third party tool which can only access data using jdbc driver only. Does anyone know how can I connect to gemfire cache for accessing data using jdbc? I don't require to write to cache, just want to read from the cache.

I came across with gemfirexd on internet but can see that its marked as "End of availability".

Is there any other way where persisted Objects can be retrieved or OQL can be fired but can mimic a jdbc driver so that the any tool that accepts only jdbc drivers can be used?

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Calcite has a [Geode adapter](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/geode_adapter.html) that enables you read data from GemFire over JDBC. There is also this [video](https://content.pivotal.io/youtube-all-videos/enable-sql-jdbc-access-to-apache-geode-gemfire-using-apache-calcite-christian-tzolov-2) explaining this.

Comment: According to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49411169/apache-calcite-geode-jdbc-adapte-not-working-with-gemfire-8-x-and-9-x I won't be able to use geode with gemfire 8.x (which I have and cannot upgrade to 9)

Comment: do you have any other idea for this?